# Xamarin, Android. Exception when opening *.axml files in VS2015 using F#,

Tags: android, xamarin, visual-studio-2015, f#

I receive the following error message when opening layout files in `F#` project.

[image]

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance
>   of an object. at
>   Xamarin.VisualStudio.Android.MonoAndroidDesignerInterface.VisualStudioCodeModelBridge.get_EnclosingProject()
>   in
>   c:\Users\builder\data\lanes\3822\3b7df6f5\source\xamarinvs\src\Core\VisualStudio.Android\Designer\MonoAndroidDesignerInterface.cs:line
>   180 at
>   Xamarin.AndroidDesigner.CodeInteractions.CodeModelBridge.d__12.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) at
>   Xamarin.AndroidDesigner.CodeInteractions.CodeModelBridge.d__27.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) at Xamarin.AndroidDesigner.DesignerProject.d__175.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) at Xamarin.AndroidDesigner.DesignerProject.d__139.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) at
>   Xamarin.AndroidDesigner.AndroidRenderSession.d__105.MoveNext()`

Never had this problem before, until I updated Xamarin to the latest
version. I've found related bug here
https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=44956, but it says that
it's a duplicate of another one which is
https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=44797, but I can't access
it.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned, this appears to be [public bug report 44956](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=44956), which is currently under investigation. Bug 44797 was filed as a private issue by the individual reporting it; as such, only the original reporter and the Xamarin team can access it.

The private bug has been closed as a duplicate of this public report, so future updates on the status of the bug from the Xamarin team will be made via [Bug 44956](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=44956).