# Xamarin for Visual Studio wont load axml file for F# project

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, f#

I am trying to make an F# app through Xamarin for Visual studio.

Whenever i try to open axml file then i get the error "The layout could not be loaded"

[image]

```
 System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Xamarin.VisualStudio.Android.MonoAndroidDesignerInterface.VisualStudioCodeModelBridge.get_EnclosingProject() in C:\data\lanes\3513\872717c9\source\xamarinvs\src\Core\VisualStudio.Android\Designer\MonoAndroidDesignerInterface.cs:line 180
   at Xamarin.AndroidDesigner.CodeInteractions.CodeModelBridge.<GetCompilationAsync>d__12.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Xamarin.AndroidDesigner.CodeInteractions.CodeModelBridge.<GetDesignerResourceEntries>d__27.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Xamarin.AndroidDesigner.DesignerProject.<UpdateDesignerResourceIds>d__175.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Xamarin.AndroidDesigner.DesignerProject.<EnsureLoaded>d__139.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Xamarin.AndroidDesigner.AndroidRenderSession.<InitSession>d__105.MoveNext()
```

The funny thing is that this is only a problem if i make a F# based project. If i make a C# project then it loads the axml without problems.

any ideas?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xamarin, Android. Exception when opening \*.axml files in VS2015 using F#,](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40070400/xamarin-android-exception-when-opening-axml-files-in-vs2015-using-f)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug that has been confirmed but not fixed yet.

https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=44956